# ¿Por qué no me sale el swal alert de js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function validarRegistro(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var usuario=document.querySelector('#usuario').value.trim(),
        password=document.querySelector('#password').value.trim(),
        tipo=document.querySelector('#tipo').value;
        // Asegurarse que los campos no estén vacíos
        if (usuario==='' || password==='') {
            swal( "Error" ,  " Todos los campos son obligatorios " ,  "error" );
        }
        else{

            /* En caso que los datos sean correctos llamamos a AJAX. Pero primero debemos enviar mediante formdata */
            const datos=new FormData();
            datos.append('usuario', usuario);
            datos.append('password', password);
            datos.append('accion', tipo);

            /* Creacion del objeto Ajax */
            const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

            /* Apertura de la conexion del objeto Ajax */
            xhr.open('POST','includes/modelos/modelo-admin.php',true);

            /* Envío de datos a través de Ajax------------- */
            xhr.onload=function(){
                if(this.status===200){ 
                    var respuesta=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if (respuesta.respuesta==='correcto'){
                        if(respuesta.tipo==='crear'){
                             swal( "éxito" , "Contacto creado con éxito", "success");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

```css
<?php

$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$accion=$_POST['accion'];

if($accion==='crear'){

    /*Primero se hace e3l hash del password--------- */
    $opciones=array(
        'coste'=>12
    );

    /* Se cifra con la función password_hash. Esta recibe tres parámetros para su funcionamiento
    1) El string de la contraseña, 2) el modo de encriptación y 3) el coste que usualmente es un entero */
    $cifrado=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$opciones);

    /* $resultado=array(
        'usuario'=>$usuario,
        'password'=>$cifrado
    ); */
    //echo json_encode($resultado,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    include '../funciones/conexion.php';

    try {
        //Conectando a la base de datos con el statement
        $stmt=$conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios(usuario, clave) VALUES(?,?)');
        //Parametrizar los statements
        $stmt->bind_param('ss',$usuario,$cifrado);
        // Ejecución de la consulta
        $stmt->execute();

        //Validar que una columna se vea modificada
        if ($stmt->affected_rows){
                 $respuesta=array(
                'respuesta'=>'correcto',
                'id'=>$stmt->insert_id,
                'tipo'=>$accion
            );

        }

        //Cierre del statement y la conexión
        $stmt->close();
        $conexion->close();

    } catch (Exception $e){
        //Excepcion en caso de haber un error

        $respuesta=array(
            'pass'->$e->getMessage()
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($respuesta,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-formulario">
        <h1>UpTask <span>Crear Cuenta</span></h1>
        <form id="formulario" class=" caja-login" method="post">
            <div class="campo">
                <label for="usuario">Usuario: </label>
                <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
            </div>
            <div class="campo">
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="campo enviar">
            <!--Envío una variable oculta-->
                <input type="hidden" id="tipo" value="crear">
                <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Crear cuenta">
            </div>
            <div class="campo">
                <a href="login.html">Inicia Sesión Aquí</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Una vez tengo este codigo que supongo está bien me debería saler una ventana de alert pero no me sale nada cuando inserto el usuario y la nueva contraseña.

Alguien puede tenerme una mano?

Comment: Haz un `console.log(xhr.responseText);` en la parte del  `onload` y revisa la consola para verificar si está trayendo algo del servidor y cómo lo está trayendo.

Comment: A. cedano si me da esto: Object
id: 60
respuesta: "correcto"
tipo: "crear"  Lo anterior me deja ver que si esta trayendo los datos pero no se porque no se ejecuta mas

Comment: No veo claro qué estructura tendría tu objeto, ¿qué muestra esto?: `console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));` Quizá no te hace falta hacer el `JSON.parse`, intenta declarando la variable así solamente: **`var respuesta=xhr.responseText;`**

Comment: object </br> id:62 </br> respuesta: 'correcto' </br> tipo:'crear'

Comment: ¿Si declaras la variable así solamente no funciona: **`var respuesta=xhr.responseText;`**? Y otra cosa, prueba con un alert normal:  `alert('Todo OK');`

Comment: Sale igual. Lo que he notado es que aun quitando esa linea de la consola (consol.log) se sigue mostrando en la consola de chrome el object que te mencioné arriba :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91458/discussion-between-jesu-and-a-cedano).

Comment: A. Cedano encontré el problema. Tenia que ver con el caché del navegador. Lo solucioné poniendo la función  echo time en la etiqueta que enlaza a mi archivo así: <script src="js/formulario.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>

Comment: Bueno, pero no es que tengas que poner `echo time();`, la gestión del caché es mejor hacerla desde otra parte como el `.htaccess` o algo así, indicando qué cosas quieres guardar en caché y qué cosas no. Pero, ¿de las soluciones propuestas con cuál funcionó? Yo pondría los encabezados en el PHP e indicaría el contenType  en  xhr.

Comment: comp puedo hacer esa sentencia? Es bueno saberlo para un ponerlo siempre desde el código php

Comment: ¿Qué sentencia?